# checking if a loop returned a value

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to test my list if it ever give any result at all then give the ok to run an other list. Do i have to make a new 'for' statement that run my list again? sry for bad english

I found these statement but im trying to figure out how i can apply them to my code.

**But how do I check if my loop never ran at all?**

The easiest way to check if a for loop never executed is to use None as a sentinel value:

```
x = None
for x in data:
    ... # process x
if x is None:
    raise ValueError("Empty data iterable: {!r:100}".format(data))
If None is a legitimate data value, then a custom sentinel object can be used instead:
```

---

```
x = _empty = object()
for x in data:
    ... # process x
if x is _empty:
    raise ValueError("Empty data iterable: {!r:100}".format(data))
```

---

**My usecase:**

```
message = ["potato:23", "orange:", "apple:22"]

for i in message:
    parts = i.split(":")
    gauche = parts[0].strip()
    droite = parts[1]

    try:
        droite = int(droite)
        if not gauche.isalpha():
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            break
```

---

```
# following code runs if no error was raised in the for loop
message2 = sorted(ligne(texte))
for j in message2:
    print(j)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: I can see you're trying but the question is not clear, I suggest include a small example sample with the desired input and output

Comment: Yes the list of items will have lines with a  in each of them string : integer   and its testing it out if there are missing stuff or wrong stuff entered. There's an exemple in the modified question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: I would like to execute this like of code if that for didnt raise any error

As you want to continue your programm, you couldn't use `raise`.
For instance, I `append` all `gauche` if `int(droite)` **didn't** `raise ValueError` and `gauche.isalpha`.
Sort this list of fruits and `print` it.

```
ligne = []
for i in message:
    parts = i.split(":")
    gauche = parts[0].strip()
    droite = parts[1]
    try:
        droite = int(droite)
        if not gauche.isalpha():
            #raise Exception("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))
            print("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))
        else:
            # Append only if isalpha
            ligne.append((gauche))

    except ValueError:
        #raise Exception("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))
        print("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))


message2 = sorted(ligne)
for fruit in message2:
    print(fruit)
```

> **Output**:
>   La ligne 'orange:' n'est pas correctement formaté.
>   apple
>   potato

---

Tried your code, it's working for me.
I get the following output:

```
La ligne ' orange: ' n'est pas correctement formaté.
```

> **Question**:I found these statement but im trying to figure out how i can apply them to my code

You can use it for instance:

```
try:
    droite = int(droite)
    if not gauche.isalpha():
        raise Exception("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))
except ValueError:
    raise Exception("La ligne {!r:2} n'est pas correctement formaté.".format(i))
```

Comment: After that line of code, i would like to know if i will be to run an other 'For' if this part of the code didnt raise any exeption?

Comment: yes. after the whole code i just wrote above i would like to add an other for block on the same level.

Comment: Ok i have edited my code with the block i would like to add under if the raise didnt return any error.

Comment: i get  this error ..........message = sorted(ligne(texte))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ligne' referenced before assignment.......ive also tried the message = sorted(ligne) like you said and it didn't work too

Comment: Check if you have **the first line** of my Answers code. There `ligne = []` are instantiated.